# How to install pytorch in windows?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, pytorch, conda

I am trying to install pytorch on windows and there is one which is available for it but shows an error.

```
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch=0.1.12
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: **Note**: There's no reason to rely on the answers here, you can find installation instructions at https://pytorch.org.

Comment: Yeah, it helped me to just set up the settings you need in the official site and copy the appropriate command to install PyTorch.

Answer (score 31):

**Warning: Unless you have a very specific reason not to, just follow the official installation instructions from https://pytorch.org. They are far more likely to be accurate and up-to-date.**

---

Here is how to install the PyTorch package from the official channel, on Windows using Anaconda, as of the time of writing this comment (31/03/2020):

PyTorch without CUDA:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch
```

PyTorch with CUDA 10.1:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch
```

Comment: Why would you install without CUDA?

Comment: @Lucas What if he doesn't have a GPU?

Comment: Can't it be installed without the heavy "conda" framework?

Comment: @PhilMacKay _Can't it be installed without the heavy "conda" framework?_ Conda isn't particularly heavy, I imagine you're referring to Anaconda?

Comment: What is the `pip3 install torchvision` for?

Comment: @AMC Yeah, I tend to forget that we can install "conda" without Anaconda ;) Still, "conda" takes an eternity to resolve package dependency. From PyTorch's website, we can use `pip install [...] -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`. It would be nice to have the windows-compatible version on PyPI!

Comment: @PhilMacKay _Still, "conda" takes an eternity_ To download, or to install? Or are you referring to the time it takes to resolve dependencies? According to the Anaconda website, Miniconda is 50 MB (the installer, at least).

Answer (score 21):

go to the official website: http://pytorch.org/

1. Select Windows as your operating system
2. Select your Package Manager such as pip or conda
3. Select you python version
4. Select CUDA or choose none
   You will get the command that will install pytorch on your system based on your selection.

For example, if you choose **Windows, pip, python 3.6** and **none** in the listed steps, you will get the following commands:

```
pip3 install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-0.4.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl 
pip3 install torchvision
```

Answer (score 10):

**Actual answer**:

---

Best way is to check on the [official website](https://pytorch.org/) for up-to-date options. Here are the ones working as of 2020-03:

```
# for windows 10, CUDA 10.1
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch

#for windows 10, CUDA 9
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=9.2 -c pytorch -c defaults -c numba/label/dev
```

Previous answer(out-of-date)

---

It seems that the author (peterjc123) released 2 days ago conda packages to install PyTorch 0.3.0 on windows. Here is a copy:

```
# for Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016, CUDA 8
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch cuda80

# for Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016, CUDA 9
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch cuda90

# for Windows 7/8/8.1 and Windows Server 2008/2012, CUDA 8
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch_legacy cuda80
```

source: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/494#issuecomment-350527200

Comment: This is out of date.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer! :)

Answer (score 10):

If you are trying to install on windows 10 and you are not having the anaconda installation than the best options are below:

## Python 2.7

```
pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.0.1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
pip install torchvision
```

If the above command does not work, then you have python 2.7 UCS2, use this command

```
pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.0.1-cp27-cp27m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

## Python 3.5

```
pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
pip3 install torchvision
```

## Python 3.6

```
pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
pip3 install torchvision
```

## Python 3.7

```
pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.0.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
pip3 install torchvision
```

Comment: _you are not having the anaconda installation_ What do you mean?

Comment: It mean Anaconda distribution is not installed on you computer.

Answer (score 4):

Update June 2019: pytorch has a dedicated conda channel now and can be installed easily with anaconda. The command generated at pytorch will require dependencies before it can be executed successfully. For example I chose stable pytorch 1.1 build with python 3.6 and Cuda 10.0. The command generated by pytorch page was as follows:

> conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.0 -c pytorch

But it will not work if you have created a new conda environment like me. The step by step process for setting up pytorch is as follows:

- First install the cudatoolkit as follows:

> conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit=10.0

- Then install the mkl_fft as follows:

> conda install -c anaconda mkl_fft

- Assuming you will face no more dependency issues. Use the following command to setup pytorch:

> conda install -c pytorch pytorch

This worked for me. But I had setup my new conda environment with scikit-learn and jupyter notebook before starting the pytorch setup. So if any dependency problem arise, it would be a good idea to install both scikit-learn and jupyter notebook as well.

Comment: _But it will not work if you have created a new conda environment like me._ What do you mean? Why do you need to install these dependencies manually?

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to go to the PyTorch [website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) and select the things you need:

[image]

Comment: hi can u help with installing pytorch on win32bit? they say they dont support it on win32bit...

Comment: The real answer.

Comment: I think you should circle in red the "run this command". I was looking at a link before or something more obvious but I had the command in straight into my face lol.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/). This would enable you to install pytorch as you would on Linux. Although, I believe that DfW has limited CUDA support, so you may want to explore a different option if you plan on using CUDA.

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```
conda install -c pytorch pytorch
```

The command will update/install: conda, cudatoolkit, pytorch.

Answer (score 1):

pip install torch==1.5.0+cpu torchvision==0.6.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

Answer (score 0):

I was getting some kind of `Rollback error` on Git bash and Windows Cmd prompt so had to run Anaconda prompt as admin for:

`conda install pytorch-cpu -c pytorch`

and then I got another when I tried the following command on Anaconda prompt:

`pip3 install torchvision`

so I switched back to Windows prompt to enter it and it worked.

To test the installation, I ran this from Git Bash:

`$ python reinforcement_q_learning.py`

with source code that looks like (the snippet near the top anyways):

```
"""

import gym
import math
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import count
from PIL import Image

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torchvision.transforms as T


env = gym.make('CartPole-v0').unwrapped

# set up matplotlib
is_ipython = 'inline' in matplotlib.get_backend()
if is_ipython:
    from IPython import display

plt.ion()

# if gpu is to be used
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")


######################################################################
# Replay Memory
# -------------
#
# We'll be using experience replay memory for training our DQN. It stores
# the transitions that the agent observes, allowing us to reuse this data
# later. By sampling from it randomly, the transitions that build up a
# batch are decorrelated. It has been shown that this greatly stabilizes
# and improves the DQN training procedure.
#
# For this, we're going to need two classses:
#
# -  ``Transition`` - a named tuple representing a single transition in
#    our environment. It maps essentially maps (state, action) pairs
#    to their (next_state, reward) result, with the state being the
#    screen difference image as described later on.
# -  ``ReplayMemory`` - a cyclic buffer of bounded size that holds the
#    transitions observed recently. It also implements a ``.sample()``
#    method for selecting a random batch of transitions for training.
#

Transition = namedtuple('Transition',
                        ('state', 'action', 'next_state', 'reward'))


class ReplayMemory(object):

    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.memory = []
        self.position = 0

    def push(self, *args):
        """Saves a transition."""
        if len(self.memory) < self.capacity:
            self.memory.append(None)
        self.memory[self.position] = Transition(*args)
        self.position = (self.position + 1) % self.capacity

    def sample(self, batch_size):
        return random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.memory)

############continues to line 507...
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to use pip for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. cd C:\Program files\Anaconda3\condabin
2. conda install pytorch-cpu torchvision-cpu -c pytorch

https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#anaconda

Comment: Why change directories?

Comment: because conda may not be in path

Answer (score 0):

for python 3.7 which is the latest till date

for pytorch on cpu

`pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.0.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`

`pip install torchvision`

Comment: OP is clearly using Anaconda/Conda, as such this solution is simply not good.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the official website(https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) where the following command is mentioned for Windows 10 & Conda environment:

> conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch

I ran this command in Anaconda command prompt but I was getting stuck as there were following errors

> ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::pycurl-7.43.0.1-py36h74b6da3_0'.
>   WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied')

To rectify this I opened the Anaconda command prompt as administrator and then ran the same command again. It solved the access issue and allowed the package to get installed.

So you just have to use following two steps:

Step 1: Open Anaconda prompt as administrator

Step 2: run following command

> conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working configuration:

Python 3.8

Pytorch version 1.5.1

Windows 10

pytorch installation command:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=9.2 -c pytorch -c defaults -c numba/label/dev
```

Answer (score -1):

If @x0s answer gives dependency issues then try updating conda before that.

```
conda update conda  
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch_legacy cuda80
```

Comment: This is out of date.

Answer (score -1):

This Line of code did the trick for me:

```
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch
```

Check these links out in case you have any problem installing:

[Superdatascience Tutorial](https://www.superdatascience.com/pytorch/)
 Explains Clearly how to do it.

Or just go to the anaconda pytorch page: https://anaconda.org/peterjc123/pytorch

It worked for me.Hope my answer was useful.

Comment: This is out of date.