# Getting error while installing Flair (NLP Library)

Tags: python, cmd, installation, pip, pytorch

I am trying to install NLP library "Flair" using pip and getting the error message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.0.0 (from flair) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch>=1.0.0 (from flair)"
```

What should I do

I am using python3.6 and tried to install flair using cmd and pip in virtualenv. But there is still error messages.

```
(env) C:\Users\HP>pip install flair
```

I want the installation without any issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcX4O.png)

Comment: `pip install torch` ?

Answer (score 2):

Pytorch or torch is currently cannot be installed using pypi in windows.
You will need conda to accomplish that:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=9.0 -c pytorch
```

**OR**

for older torch version you can use whl file, Cuda version can be 8.0,9.0,10.0

```
pip install torch==1.0.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu90/stable # CUDA 9.0 build
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by installing the following packages :

```
!pip install tiny-tokenizer flair
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error.

Below steps worked for me on **Windows10,Python3.6**

1.Installing Pytorch by following the official installation instructions from https://pytorch.org The have well documented details.

Based on your selection of package [pip/conda etc] and OS [Mac/Linus/Windows] it will provide command .
This link provides useful details on how to install pytorch -
[how to install pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754749/how-to-install-pytorch-in-windows)

2.After successful installation of pytorch,just install Flair using command
`pip install flair`

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your pip and try again.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install torch
```