# Installing torch using pip / Visual Studio

Tags: python, pip, installation, pytorch, torch

I'm trying every which way to install torch via Visual Studio, yet keep getting the below errors.

Any suggestions on what to do? Have seen some mention that the normal pip install torch command does not work as intended, but as I'm fairly new to Python I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
----- Installing 'torch' -----
Collecting torch
  Using cached torch-0.1.2.post2.tar.gz (128 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyyaml in c:\users\`\desktop\python projects\deeprl\deeprl\lib\site-packages (from torch) (5.3)
Installing collected packages: torch
    Running setup.py install for torch: started
    Running setup.py install for torch: finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\`\Desktop\Python Projects\DeepRL\DeepRL\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\`\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6ouq_hzc\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\`\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6ouq_hzc\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\`\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-lfjewv4e\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\`\Desktop\Python Projects\DeepRL\DeepRL\include\site\python3.7\torch'
         cwd: C:\Users\`\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6ouq_hzc\torch\
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running install
    running build_deps
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\`\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6ouq_hzc\torch\setup.py", line 265, in <module>
        description="Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration",
      File "C:\Users\`\Desktop\Python Projects\DeepRL\DeepRL\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\`\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6ouq_hzc\torch\setup.py", line 99, in run
        self.run_command('build_deps')
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\`\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6ouq_hzc\torch\setup.py", line 51, in run
        from tools.nnwrap import generate_wrappers as generate_nn_wrappers
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\`\Desktop\Python Projects\DeepRL\DeepRL\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\`\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6ouq_hzc\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\`\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6ouq_hzc\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\`\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-lfjewv4e\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\`\Desktop\Python Projects\DeepRL\DeepRL\include\site\python3.7\torch' Check the logs for full command output.
----- Failed to install 'torch' -----
```

Comment: Are you using cpu or gpu?

Comment: @Cs150 Would imagine it's CPU as I've not specified GPU.

Comment: Refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754749/how-to-install-pytorch-in-windows

Comment: @Cs150 Thanks, that worked! I feel silly now...

Comment: What command did you use? Are you not using virtual environments? Conda would be a good idea, especially since you're on Windows.

Comment: @AMC i am using virtual environments but pip install torch did not work. However Cs150 provided the solution by virtue of the link with a comprehensive answer.

Comment: @youjustreadthis What are you using for virtual environments, which tool?