# Install torch on python 3.8.1 windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I have been reading this post [How to install pytorch in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754749/how-to-install-pytorch-in-windows#new-answer?newreg=b73b26ef763246269f82290a49038a60) but no one answer work for me on the versio 3.8.1 of python. Anything else I can do?

Comment: What error are you even facing? Simply saying you're facing one doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you.

```
pip install torch==1.5.0+cpu torchvision==0.6.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Please ensure that you have met the prerequisites, depending on your package manager. You can also use Anaconda as a package manager since it installs all dependencies.

Comment: Nope. It show this error: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.5.0+cpu (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.5.0+cpu

Comment: You can try this pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu101/torch-1.4.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu101/torchvision-0.5.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

Comment: have you installed  Anaconda

Comment: Nope, I only have tha basic python. I would like to learn it simple but if still whitout working maybe try to use anaconda

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this [website](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)? Or you can try downloading from [Github](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch). By the way, it requires numpy and mkl. Downloading to a virtual environment might help too.
Hope you install it successfully!

Comment: Nope, i gone a try the website o the github thanks, also I don´t know what is mkl I gone a look for it an install. Thanks

Comment: You can download numpy+mkl [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)

Comment: pytorch [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pytorch), you can write `pip install <filename>.whl` in cmd (replace filename as the name of the file downloaded)