# How to install torch with conda on window?

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch, conda, torch

I am getting this one issue you can check in picture:

[image: problem which i am facing]

[image: pytorch and Torchversion already installed]

Can you suggest me any solid solution?

I am new here please give me a solution rather than checking my question style. Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install pytorch in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754749/how-to-install-pytorch-in-windows)

Comment: No this is not my solution because every thing which is mentioned in that solution i have installed already. But my question is that how to install torch? whenever i try to install this give me same issue which i have attached in the picture

Comment: The Conda package `pytorch` is the equivalent of the PyPI package `torch`. Have you tried checking `import torch` in the env that has `pytorch` installed?